# Как сделать внутреннюю тень у текста который размещен на фоне?

Tags: css

Нужно что то типа такого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
div {
  background: url('https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/branco-tijolos-texturas-de-parede-de-fundo_1203-3691.jpg');
  width: 460px;
  height: 120px;
}
h1 {
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 62px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример

```css
div {
  background: url('https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/branco-tijolos-texturas-de-parede-de-fundo_1203-3691.jpg');
  width: 460px;
  height: 120px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 62px;
  background-color: #111;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: -2px 2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);  
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Это грубый пример. поиграй с тенями и добьешься желаемого результата...

```css
div {
  background: url('https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/branco-tijolos-texturas-de-parede-de-fundo_1203-3691.jpg');
  width: 460px;
  height: 120px;
}

h1 {
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 62px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgb(100, 108, 42), 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 2px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, .5);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</div>
```