# Собственно, такой вопрос, как сделать тиснение в CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3, photoshop, psd

Здравствуйте уважаемые коддры!

Возник такой интересный вопрос, как можно сделать тиснение в css для кнопки ?

Есть кнопка (пр. ниже), у  неё задано тиснение:

---

[image: скриншот]
 - Как определить эти стили в CSS ?

Цвет градиента **#8d6262** и
   **#393232**, думал через text-shadow, но оно не хочет так работать, может кто-то из вас знает ?

**btn-size** : 460 пикс. на 77 пикс.

**border-radius** : 38.5 пикс.

Благодарю, что дочитали до конца! ;)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать внутреннюю тень у текста который размещен на фоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859301/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8e%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5)

Answer (score 5):

Можно добавить несколько теней – внешнюю, внутреннюю черную, внутреннюю белую:

```css
body {
  background: wheat;
  padding: 50px;
}

.btn {
  width: 460px;
  height: 77px;
  border-radius: 38.5px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #8d6262, #393232);
  box-shadow: 
  2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 
  inset -4px -4px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4), 
  inset 4px 4px 20px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn"></div>
```

Comment: во, то что нужно, благодарю Артём ;)

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Leckerli+One');
body {
  font-family: 'Leckerli One', cursive;
  font-size: 600%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #aaa;
  font-style: italic;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
```

Можно почитать тут : https://habr.com/post/137005/